# Use Python to solve a probability problem

Tags: python, probability, stat

Here's the problem:
There are n people in a room, each person has a probability to leave.

For example, there are 3 people A,B,C in the room, A has a probability of 30% to leave the room, B has a probability of 50% to leave, and for C is 80%.

There are 4 possible result: 0, 1, 2 or all 3 people left the room. Every result has a probability. for instance, 30%*50%*80% = 12% is the probability that all three people leave, 30%*50%*(1-80%) + 30%*(1-50%)*80%* +(1-30%)+50%*80 = 79% is the probability that exactly two people leave.

I tryed to write a Python program:

Input:

- n: integer, the number of people in the room.
- personProb: a list of length n, at index k is the probability of **kth** person leave.

Output:

- resultProb: a list of length n+1, at index k is the probability of exactly k people leave.

I got stuck almost immediately when I start coding:

```
probList = []
for k in range(n+1): # k represents the number of people who will leave
```

For any k from 0 to n, I should consider all combination of k people out of n, compute (the product of selected k probabilities)*(product of (1-"not selected probabilities")).

How can I do it? How to enumerate the combinations?

For k = 2, I recall that I used to hear about a method called "double pointer", but what about when k>2? is there a "k pointer"?

Comment: *Maybe* this is something for http://stats.stackexchange.com or similar [sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites). If it's a *coding* problem, provide more *code*.

Comment: @deceze Sorry! This is a coding problem, but it needs statistics knowledge. I am not sure which site should I publish it.

Comment: Well, do you have the statistics knowledge already?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes. In fact, it only requires high school level probability knowledge. But I failed to write a python code for it

Comment: Okay, so. In your own words, what are the logical steps that need to be followed to solve the problem? Where do you get stuck when you try to write the code? What exactly does "compute all n possibilities by multiplication rule" mean?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Okay, I have edited my question and replace the problem with a story-like one, hope that make it clearer.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "python enumerate" and "python combinations"?

Comment: Your code is too short to qualify as a coding problem. Try implementing what you wrote as Input, Output and your computation algorithm into a python script. Include that code script in your question and also the error msg from executing your code.